# Firebase Ionic2/Cordova Security Permissions

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2

What's the minimum set of Firebase permissions required for an Ionic2/Cordova app? Current settings are below. If default-src or script-src is set to 'self' then errors occur when calling Firebase APIs. I'm unable to see any other domains (other than listed below) to whitelist.

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap://ready https://ssl.gstatic.com file://* ws://* wss://*; img-src * data:; font-src * data:; script-src * https://*.google-analytics.com https://*.googleapis.com https://*.firebaseio.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="https://*.google-analytics.com"/>
<access origin="https://*.googleapis.com"/>
<access origin="https://*.firebaseio.com"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```